# Unable to parse document faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf

StackTrace:

```
    Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /CS230_Projekat_StefanJankovic_3750
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'jndi:/server/CS230_Projekat_StefanJankovic_3750/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml': null
```

And my faces-config.xml

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="https://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    https://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">



<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>admin</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/admin.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

I really dont know what to do. First I was getting null pointer exception for one of my method and now this.

Comment: Look at the file Named in the message. It might be something else.

Comment: I dont know is this useful but i got this also when trying to clean and build project: `Unable to delete file C:\Users\stefa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CS230_Projekat_StefanJankovic_3750\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\cssparser-0.9.18.jar`

Comment: Remove any character (spaces, tabs) at the beginning of the very first line `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>` -- I can see two spaces right there.

Comment: I didn't know this was so sensitive. Thank you.

Comment: XML parsers are, effectively not a jsf thing. But I'm almost 100% sure there must have been a more detailed error in your logging. Something about content not allowed in prolog